# Vim enum indent for C++

Tags: indentation

When I use auto indent in vim, it almost working correctly, but in C++ 's **enum**, it have some problem like this:

[image]

It should be like this:

[image]

My indent settings:

```
set expandtab       
set tabstop=4       
set smartindent     
set autoindent      
set shiftwidth=2    
set softtabstop=4
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem. Do you still have an issue if you delete every line in your `.vimrc` other than these indent settings?

Comment: It still have issue.
I have try delete some plugin that controling filetype and it still not working correct.

Comment: Use clang-format to auto format the code, it's much better than auto indent